# bash run curl from another script

Tags: bash, curl

in win7 cmder (git-for-windows?)

lib:

```sh
set -x
curl.exe -s $1
echo $?
echo $1
```

`lib` works perfect alone.

> the `set -x` show:
>
> ```
> + curl.exe -s 'https://example.com'
> ```

Now, run `lib` from other script.

librun.sh:

```sh
FILE=url.txt
while read line; do
  bash lib $line
done < "$FILE"
```

Here, the `curl` return error code 3.

> the `set -x` show:
>
> ```
> + curl.exe -s $'https://example.com\r'
> ```

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title. If you want to indicate that your question has been answered, you can click the hollow checkmark in the left-hand margin of the answer that you found most helpful; please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
$'https://example.com\r'
```

indicates that url.txt contains [Windows line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation). Convert them to UNIX line endings:

```
dos2unix url.txt
```